# How to prepare to run X km in Y minutes?

Tags: running

My friend needs to be able to run 2km in 8 minutes for a physical test, and I found his current schedule to achieve that interesting, because i'll have to do it soon too. But I come here to see if any runners have a better preparation schedule.

If you know you need to run X km in Y minutes how do you prepare for that? I'd like a question that can work for many people. Consider a reasonable time

I would like to know about this too:

- Metrics you use for progress(e.g being able to run faster without getting tired or running longer?)

  Consider that the person have no previous experience with running, not more than the average 30min in the gym for weight loss

Comment: FYI taking the title literally, running X km in X minutes for a single value of X, would be running 60 kph or 38 mph.

Answer (score 1):

An article in the "Journal of science and medicine in sport" suggest that a warm-up consisting of a 10-min self-paced jog, a 5-min submaximal run to determine running economy, and six 10-s strides with a weighted-vest (20% of body mass) has a positive effect leg stiffness and running economy and in turn a large increase in top running speed.

That's for warm up.

As goes for workout I'd suggest High intensity interval training.

It's proven to be far more effective in increasing pulmonary strength than regular endurance training.

Comment: HIIT does increase pulmonary strength, but the myths about being able to run long distances effectively only doing HIIT training are just that, myths. Also, if you could provide a link to the article in question, it would be nice.