# How to train to run 2.5 km from scratch?

Tags: running, running-training-plan, beginners, triathlon

**Context**: I am a 50-year-old man, out of shape and somehow overweight (by European standards). I would like to prepare for a µ-baby-family triathlon (300 m / 330 yards swimming + 8 km / 5 mi bike + 2.5 km / 1.5 mi run) because it is a reasonable goal for me to get fitter and overall healthier.
I can swim the 300 m, I irregularly bike 2 x 15 km (10 mi) a day to commute to the office.
My overall health is OK-ish, I did a general checkup and a targeted cardio one recently.

**My problem**: the running part is killing me: I am out of breath after a short distance (no pain or anything, just the sensation of having ran 10x the distance)

**My question**: to reach these 2.5 km<sup>(*)</sup> is it better to

- alternate "harder" runs (not sprints yet) and walk in between
- or run as slowly as needed, but run continuously
- or something in between?

One of the [answers on a vaguely related question](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/27444/29129) mentions High Intensity Interval Training which would point towards the first approach. The questions I found are however mostly about mid to advanced athletes and not a beginner like myself, thus my introduction at the beginning.

---

<sup>(*)</sup> it is just one of the three exercises, I am ultimately aiming at doubling the distance for each of them when done separately to have some reserves

Comment: I am sorry for such a basic point but I would simply say do it again and again and again and you will improve. Some approaches might be better than others but in the end the important thing is simply to train regularly. Therefore I would pick a method I like and keep trying

Comment: @LulY thanks - this is a perfectly reasonable answer. My concern was with the fact that sometimes if you do not reach a specific "something" (speed, heart rate, time, ...)) it is equivalent to doing almost nothing. Or going the super slow way that discourages a lot of people.